# VB.NET Inherits Object, pass object as variable

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to create Object "B" from "A" without having to set each indivdual property, i'm essetiall trying to achieve this:

```
Class A
Public Property1 as integer
Public Property2 as integer
Public Property...
End class

Class B
Inherits A
Public Addtional_Property as integer

Sub New(Input as A)
 Me = Input
End Sub
End class
```

instead of this:

```
Sub New(Input as A)
Me.Property1 =Input.Property1 
Me.Property2 =Input.Property3 
Me.Property... =Input.Property... 
End Sub
```

Comment: No there isn't what you have shown there implies that the current object could somehow become a different object, which is nonsensical.  You're dealing with two distinct objects, so you have no choice but to copy data from one to the other.  A "copy constructor" like you have shown is a common way to do that.

Comment: In the constructor of B, you could have something like: `Public Sub New(a As A)
 If a IsNot Nothing Then For Each p As PropertyInfo In a.GetType().GetProperties() Dim myP As PropertyInfo = Me.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name) If myP.CanWrite Then myP.SetValue(Me, p.GetValue(a)) Next End If End Sub`

Comment: @Fabio Meaning? The base is not abstract nor the properties are virtual. The inheriting class doesn't shadow any of the inherited properties. All is inherited as-is. Just setting values. The types are the same. Not that I want to *defend* the micro snippet, just to clarify.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I forgot that properties of "same type" are mapped.